# BAD_USER_INPUT Error on Edit value on form user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo-client

**Problem**

I'm currently working on reactjs + apollo client projects. I'm developing edit user feature. for querying user by username, it works.

[image]

but when i'm change the data information. it throws error like this.

[image]

Also , i'm getting this error.

[image]

**Code**

Mutation

```
  mutation($username: String!, $input: EditUser!) {
        updateUser(username: $username, input: $input) {
            full_name
            email
            group_id
            phone
            address
        }
    }
```

ModalEdit.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useQuery, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { Button, Modal, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

import { GET_USER_BY_ID } from "../../../gql/query";
import { UPDATE_USER } from "../../../gql/mutation";

const ModalEdit = (props) => {
  // state for check input component
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState("ACTIVE");

  // state for input values
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    group_id: "",
    full_name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
    address: "",
    password: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.show) {
      document.body.classList.add("modal-open");
    }

    return () => {
      if (document.body.classList.contains("modal-open")) {
        document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
      }
    };
  }, [props.show]);

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_USER_BY_ID, {
    variables: { username: props.username },
  });

  const [updateUser, { error: updateError, loading: updateLoading, refetch }] =
    useMutation(UPDATE_USER, {
      onCompleted: (data) => {
        refetch();
      },
      onError: (err) => {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      },
    });

  const dataUser = data?.getUserByID;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (dataUser) {
      setValue({
        group_id: dataUser.group_id,
        full_name: dataUser.full_name,
        email: dataUser.email,
        phone: dataUser.phone,
        address: dataUser.address,
        password: dataUser.password,
      });
    }
  }, [dataUser]);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error!</p>;

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setValue({ ...value, [name]: value });
  };

  // handle mutation for edit user
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(value.full_name);

    updateUser({
      variables: {
        username: props.username,
        input: {
          group_id: value.group_id,
          full_name: value.full_name,
          email: value.email,
          phone: value.phone,
          address: value.address,
          password: value.password,
        },
      },
    });
  };

  return (
    <Modal show={props.show}>
      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>
          {" "}
          <span>FORMULIR AKUN PENGGUNA</span>{" "}
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Role Akun</Form.Label>
            <Form.Select
              aria-label="pilih user role"
              name="group_id"
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <option value={value.group_id}>{value.group_id}</option>
            </Form.Select>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Nama Lengkap</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="full_name"
              value={value.full_name}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={value.email}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3">
            <Form.Label>Phone</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control
              type="text"
              name="phone"
              value={value.phone}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Aktifkan Akun</Form.Label>
          {dataUser.status === "ACTIVE" ? (
            <Form.Check
              type="switch"
              checked={isChecked}
              onChange={(event) => setIsChecked(event.target.checked)}
              id="custom-switch"
              label="Aktifkan Akun"
            />
          ) : (
            <Form.Check
              type="switch"
              id="custom-switch"
              checked={isChecked}
              onChange={(event) => setIsChecked(event.target.checked)}
              label="Aktifkan Akun"
            />
          )}
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={props.onClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Modal.Body>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ModalEdit;
```

**Question**

1. How to fix BAD_USER_INPUT request?
2. How to check if email is controlled/uncontrolled components?

any help will be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like the `input type` needs a `full_name` field as well. I think your problem lies with:

```
// state for input values
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  group_id: "",
  full_name: "",
  email: "",
  phone: "",
  address: "",
  password: "",
});
...
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setValue({ ...value, [name]: value });
};
```

Because in the context of this function `value` is == `event.target.value` and not the `value` you defined in your `setState`:

Therefore `setValue({...value, [name]: value});` will completely override the state.

Try aliasing the target's value:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value:tValue } = event.target;
  setValue({ ...value, [name]: tValue });
};
```

2. I suspect this is a consequence of `value.email` suddenly becoming undefined based on (1).